# Instagram Followers

Tags: instagram

I need to display the followers list of instagram account in my website.
I have created app and generate access token successfully.

But if i run the instagram api to get the followers list, it shows me the empty result.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token={access_token}

Can anyone help me to get the followers list.

Answer (score 2):

In sandbox mode you will only see users approved to sandbox in API response.

Add one of your followers to sandbox users and let them accept it, then you will just see that user in the API response.

Once you get your app approved by Instagram and go live, you will see all (but I dont think Instagram is approving any app with permission other than basic anymore)